# QObject::connect(QQuickWindow, QDeclarativeGeoMap): invalid nullptr parameter

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I get such an error, during the start, when I run the project through QTcreator, then everything is displayed. But when I run the .exe release, the QQuickWidget doesn't show up (That's the problem).

Deployed by windeployqt tool witch --qmldir key , added lib for ssl, QtLocation, QtPositioning.

mainwidget.ccp

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include "ui_mainwidget.h"
#include "mapwindow.h"

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    map_window = new MapWindow();

    connect(map_window, &MapWindow::return_on_main_window, this, &MainWidget::show);
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWidget::on_MapButton_clicked()
{
    map_window -> show();

    this -> close();
}
```

mapwindow.cpp

```
#include "mapwindow.h"
#include "ui_mapwindow.h"

MapWindow::MapWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->MapWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/Map_QML.qml"));
    ui->MapWidget->show();
}

MapWindow::~MapWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MapWindow::on_ReturnButton_clicked()
{
    this->close();

    emit return_on_main_window();
}
```

mainwidget.h

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "mapwindow.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWidget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWidget();

private slots:
    void on_MapButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWidget *ui;
    MapWindow *map_window;
};
#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

mapwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAPWINDOW_H
#define MAPWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MapWindow;
}

class MapWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MapWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MapWindow();

signals:
    void return_on_main_window();

private slots:
    void on_ReturnButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MapWindow *ui;
};
```

Map_QML.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtLocation 5.15

Rectangle {
    id: window

    property double oldLat: 49.45466
    property double oldLng: 30.52380
    property Component comMarker: mapMarker

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter
        {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"
            value: "true"
        }
        PluginParameter
        {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.address"
            value: "http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.6/"
        }
    }

    Map {
        id: mapView
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(oldLat, oldLng);
        zoomLevel: 5.5
    }

    function setCenter(lat, lng) {
        mapView.pan(oldLat - lat, oldLng - lng)
        oldLat = lat
        oldLng = lng
    }

    function addMarker(lat, lng) {
        var item = comMarker.createObject(window, {
                                           coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lng)
                                          })
        mapView.addMapItem(item)
    }

    Component {
        id: mapMarker
        MapQuickItem {
            id: markerImg
            anchorPoint.x: image.width/4
            anchorPoint.y: image.height
            coordinate: position

            sourceItem: Image {
                id: image
                source: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to create a [mre] of this problem?  What you show here is both _a lot of code_ and incomplete.

Comment: @DrewDormann I solved this problem 5 minutes ago, I just took all the plugins, qml, bin/.dll files and pasted in the release folder. Sorry for wasting ur time :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial deployment (Quick and dirty)

1. Close Qt Creator.
2. Copy the following into C:\Deployment\
3. The release version of MyApp.exe
4. All the .dll files from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin\
5. All the folders from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\plugins\
6. (If you used QML) All the folders from C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\qml\
7. Launch C:\Deployment\MyApp.exe.

If your app worked correctly, congratulations! You are almost ready for deployment. You don't want to ship a 1.5GB package though, so it's time to clean up unused files.